# Memory consumption issues of a Java program

Tags: java, memory

I have a Java program that runs on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine and, without any user interaction, repeatedly queries a MySQL database and then constructs img- and txt-files according to the data read from the DB. It makes tens of thousands of queries and creates tens of thousands of files.

After some hours of running, the available memory on my machine including swap space is totally used up. I haven't started other programs and the processes running in the background don't consume much memory and don't really grow in consumption.

To find out what is allocating so much memory I wanted to analyse a heap dump, so I started the process with -Xms64m -Xmx128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError.

To my surprise, the situation was the same as before, after some hours the program was allocating all of the swap which is way beyond the given max of 128m.

Another run debugged with VisualVM showed that the heap allocation never is beyond the max of 128m - when the allocated memory is approximating the max, a big part of it is released again (I assume by the garbage collector).

So, it cannot be a problem a steadily growing heap.

When the memory is all used up:

free shows the following:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2060180    2004860      55320          0        848    1042908
-/+ buffers/cache:     961104    1099076
Swap:      3227640    3227640          0
```

top shows the following:

```
USER    VIRT    RES     SHR     COMMAND
[my_id] 504m    171m    4520    java
[my_id] 371m    162m    4368    java
```

(by far the two "biggest" processes and the only java processes running)

My first question is:

- How can I find out on the OS level (e.g. with command line tools) what is allocating so much memory? top / htop hasn't helped me. In case of many, many tiny processes of the same type eating up the memory: is there a way to intelligently sum up similar processes? (I know that is probably off topic as it is a Linux/Ubuntu question, but my main problem may still be Java-related)

My old questions were:

- Why isn't the memory consumption of my program given in the top output?
- How can I find out what is allocating so much memory?
- If the heap isn't the problem, is the only "allocating factor" the stack? (the
  stack shouldn't be a problem as there is no deep "method call depth")
- What about external resources as DB connections?

Comment: try to use the profiling tool: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9205812/90909

Comment: @qrtt1: I used VisualVM, but that showed that the heap isn't the problem (see above).

Comment: You can find an answer here I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/9306054/1140748 and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_oom (see the bug description)

Comment: Try MAT. It shows more details where the memory used.

Comment: @alain.janinm: >stackoverflow link: I don't see (neither with VisualVM nor with top) my java process consuming that much memory. >oracle link: I don't have an OutOfMemoryError. That's what I was trying to get in order to debug the Heap Dump.

Comment: @qrtt1: But here seems to be something fundamentally strange here. I don't see (neither with VisualVM nor with top) my java process consuming that much memory. Anyway, I will run the program with -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak (will take some hours...)

Comment: Are you mistakenly opening many simultaneous connections? Are you running any auxiliary programs which are still resident? Either of these things could cause many small processes to be created and swapped out.

Comment: Have you got a poor video card which uses system memory? Perhaps some image processing is going to the card, which is consuming more system memory than you realize, forcing other processes into swap?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions/hints. But shouldn't I see something allocating all the memory, at least with top/htop?

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue running Java version 1.6.0_29-b11 on Ubuntu.  In my case I've assigned much more memory: 16gb, but the JVM keeps going way beyond this until it hits 24gb and starts hitting swap.  I've also checked the heap size; this is correctly limited to around 14gb, but somehow the JVM process overall ends up using much more.  Did you find any answer to this?

Comment: I suspect you're opening files and writing to them and failing to close them.

Comment: Is it possible to post a code with a small dataset used in loop or even a data generator, so that we can reproduce to investigate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there was no activity after the day I asked the question (until March 23) and as I still couldn't find the cause for the memory consumption I "solved" the problem pragmatically.

The program causing the problem is basically a repetition of a "task" (i.e. querying a DB and then creating files). It is relatively easy to parameterize the program so that a certain subset of tasks is executed and not all of them.

So now I repeatedly run my program from a shell script, in each process executing only a set of tasks (parameterized through arguments). In the end, all tasks are being executed, but as a single process only processes a subset of tasks there are no memory issues any more.

For me that is a sufficient solution. If you have a similar problem and your program has a batch-like execution structure this may be a pragmatic approach.

When I find the time I will look into the new suggestions hopefully identifying the root cause (thanks for the help!).

Answer (score 7):

If indeed your Java process is the one which takes memory and there is nothing suspucios in VisualVM or memory dump then it must be somewhere in native code - either in JVM or in some of the libraries you're using. On JVM level it could be, for example, if you're using  NIO or memory mapped files. If some of your libraries are using native calls or you're using not type 4 JDBC driver for your database then leak could be there.

Some suggestions:

- There are some details how to find memory leaks in native code [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gbyvk). Good [read](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/) also.
- As usual, make sure you're properly closing all resources (Files, Streams, Connections, Threads etc). Most of these are calling native implementation at some point so memory consumed might not be directly visible in JVM
- Check resources consumed on OS level - number of open files, file descriptors, network connections etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Leaks in native code does seem like a possibility.  We don't use any native libraries that I know of though, not even JDBC.  We do of course try to be careful to close all files etc., but I do find it hard to understand how leaving such resources open could cause a JVM that has been given 16 GB of heap to consume more than 24 GB.  Surely the O/S would limit the number of open files way before that much memory had been consumed by file handles?

Comment: It's hard to give better advice without knowing internals of your program. Judging by the memory you allocating for your JVM you must be doing some sort of caching or loading lots of data from somewhere etc.  Also in original question amount of memory allocated is certainly not 16Gb, so I'm not sure if you'r referring to the same case or not.

Answer (score 2):

@maximdim's answer is great general advice for this kind of situation.  What is likely happening here is that a very small Java object is being retained that causes some larger amount of native(OS-level) memory to hang around.  This native memory is not accounted for in the Java heap.  The Java object is likely so small that you will hit your system memory limit well before the Java object retention would overwhelm the heap.

So the trick for finding this is to use successive heap dumps, far enough apart that you have noticed memory growth for the whole process, but not so far apart that a ton of work has gone on.  What you are looking for are Java object counts in the heap that keep increasing and have native memory attached.

These could be file handles, sockets, db connections, or image handles just to name a few that are likely directly applicable for you.

On more rare occasions, there is a native resource that is leaked by the java implementation, even after the Java object is garbage collected.  I once ran into a WinCE 5 bug where 4k were leaked with each socket close.  So there was no Java object growth, but there was process memory usage growth.  In these cases, it is helpful to make some counters and keep track of java allocations of objects with native memory vs. the actual growth.  Then over a short enough window, you can look for any correlations and use these to make smaller testcases.

One other hint, make sure all your close operations are in finally blocks, just in case an exception is popping you out of your normal control flow.  This has been known to cause this sort of problem as well.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your comments, that's interesting.  But as I said in the reply to @maximdim, we're seeing processes consuming a steadily incrementing amount of memory, many gigabytes more than the allocated amount of heap.  We have been carefully chasing files etc. that haven't been closed, for other reasons, but I can't see how leaving files or sockets open could cause gigabytes of memory to leak!  Also, the process in question is a server-side process, so does not using graphics libraries, load images etc...

Comment: 4K at a time for handles can add up fast if you are handling a lot of requests.  Also make sure that you are closing all your ResultSet instances in finally blocks too.  Depending on your JDBC connector version, leaking ResultSet objects could cause native memory retention.

Comment: Fair point, though it would take 2,000,000 leaked file handles at 4k a piece to leak 8Gb, and the OS limits are set much lower than that.  Also, we don't use JDBC in the process in question.

Comment: I'm confused.  The question description mentioned MySQL queries.  So if you aren't using JDBC to do that, what are you doing?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... use ipcs to check that shared memory segments aren't left open. Check the open file descriptors of your JVM (`/proc/<jvm proccess id>/fd/*`). In top, type `fpFp` to show swap and sort by used swap the task list.

That's all I can come up with for now, hope it helps at least a bit.

Answer (score 1):

As @maximdim and @JamesBranigan point out, the likely culprit is some native interaction from  your code.  But as you haven't been able to track down exactly where the problematic interaction is using available tools, why don't you try a brute force approach?

You've outlined a two part process: query MySQL and write files.  Either one of those things could be excluded from the process as a test.  Test one: eliminate the query and hard code the content that would have been returned.  Test two: do the query, but don't bother writing the files.  Do you still have leaks?

There may be other testable cases as well, depending on what else your application does.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating separate threads to run your "tasks"? The memory used to create threads is separate from the Java heap.

This means that even if you specify `-Xmx128m` the memory used by the Java process could be much higher, depending on how many threads you're using and the thread stack size (each thread gets a stack allocated, of size specified by `-Xss`).

Example from work recently:
We had a Java heap of 4GB (`-Xmx4G`), but the OS process was consuming upwards of 6GB,
also using up the swap space.
When I checked the process status with `cat /proc/<PID>/status` I noticed we had 11000 threads running.
Since we had `-Xss256K` set, this is easily explained: 10000 threads means 2,5GB.

Answer (score 0):

Your file system caching is probably causing this, the file system cache will eat up all available memory when doing a large amount of IO. You systems performance should not be adversely affected by this behaviour, the kernel will immediately release file system cache when memory is requested by a process.

Comment: But the kernel will not swap a running process until the cache is fully released...

Comment: I don't think that can be what I'm seeing; my system is indeed very adversely affected when this happens.  It will consume memory until all available RAM is used, then it will start using swap.  As you can imagine, things quickly grind to a halt very soon at that point!

Answer (score 0):

You say you are creating image files are you creating image objects? If so, are you calling dispose() on these objects when you are done?

If I remember rightly, java awt imagine objects allocate native resources that must be disposed explicitly.